# How do I make a tarball with winrar from command line

Tags: command-line, zip, winrar

This should be straight forward like it is with 7-zip, but it's not and google is not helping.

I'm doing the following at the command line

```
rar a -ep1 "C:\Mail\test.zip" "C:\Mail\LastEmail.txt"
```

and it keeps creating "test.zip" in rar archive format. It needs to be in zip format.

Ultimately I want to make a .tar.gz file.

Comment: Compression in `.zip` format is not supported in the command line version (see txt files in rar folder). Use `winrar.exe` or keep using 7zip

Comment: Good to know thanks, that might as well be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text file `Rar.txt` is the user's manual for console version `Rar.exe`.

The second and third paragraph in **Introduction** chapter at top of this file are:

> RAR supports only RAR format archives, which have .rar file name extension by default. ZIP and other formats are not supported. Even if you specify .zip extension when creating an archive, it will still be in RAR format. Windows users may install WinRAR, which supports more archive types including RAR and ZIP formats.
>
> WinRAR provides both graphical user interface and command line mode. While console RAR and GUI WinRAR have the similar command line syntax, some differences exist. So it is recommended to use this rar.txt manual for console RAR (rar.exe in case of Windows version) and winrar.chm WinRAR help file for GUI WinRAR (winrar.exe).

This is also true for free `UnRAR.exe` which is also a console application.

`WinRAR.chm` contains help of `WinRAR.exe`. On tab **Contents** there is the list item **Command line mode** with the **Command line syntax** page and the lists **Commands** and **Switches**. The page about switch **-af<type> - specify archive format** explains the difference that `WinRAR.exe` supports compressing and uncompressing ZIP archives with or without using this switch while console version `Rar.exe` does not support ZIP archives.

Comment: Yeah reading manuals goes out the window when you're in a crunch. Thanks.